# Paypal integration on an air app

Tags: php, actionscript-3, paypal, integration, ane

I know Paypal has no as3 library but are there any way to integrate payments into an AIR mobile app coded in as3 and apk compiled (maybe PHP library) gracefully futher then webview window?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read these links:

- [Development & Integration Guides](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/)
- [Methods For Integrating Digital Goods Into Flash](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/digital-goods/IntegratingDigitalGoodsInFlash/)
- [PayPal Mobile SDKs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/mobile-sdk-overview/) (**Android** and **iOS**)
- [PayPal-PHP-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK)

You have some possibilities, use the PHP SDK and integrate with your application using [URLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) or using the Mobile SDK and create a [Native Extension](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html) to integrate the native code with your ActionScript.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I saw your links before. I think "ExternalInterface.call" is unuseful in apk enviroment. Is that correct?

Comment: ANE escape my coding skills because Paypal SDK need many libs and files. Do you know any ANE/Paypal specific tutorial or resource?

Comment: PHP SDK require a page with paid SSL certificate. This is a point I would like to avoid.